# Kendo multi-select with tab key selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-multiselect

I am trying to implement a feature to select an item in kendo's multi-select control with server filtering. when user presses tab on the selected item. Here is my code of kepdown event:

```
if (e.keyCode === 9) {
       var selectedItem = multiSelect.current();

       if (selectedItem) {

            var selectedIndex = selectedItem.data("idx");

            if (selectedIndex >= 0) {

                var currentValue = multiSelect.value().slice();    
                var dataitems = multiSelect.dataSource.view();
                var selectedDataItem = dataitems[selectedIndex];

                multiSelect.dataSource.filter({});
                currentValue.push(selectedDataItem.relatedId);
                multiSelect.value(currentValue);

                multiSelect.trigger("change");
            }
         }
      }
```

But it works fine as long as I am searching in same data view i.e. lets say I select two values starting with Cloud and then I select a value starting with App then kendo will remove previous two values starting with Cloud and control will contain just one value selected at the last.

I debugged kendo's code that the issue in function _index of kendo because it finds value in dataSource.view

I have recreated the issue at http://dojo.telerik.com/OtAvi

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you have `serverFiltering` set to `true` in the dataSource:

```
dataSource: {
    type: "odata",
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
        }
    }
},
```

Since the data is being filtered on the server, the call `multiSelect.dataSource.filter({});` is only clearing the *already filtered* data. With that said, when you call `multiSelect.value(currentValue);`, only the values from the currently *filtered* dataSource can be selected. This is causing the selection to only hold items from the current dataView.

Unless you have a strong reason not to, your easiest fix is to set `serverFiltering` set to `false`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I cannot get rid of server filtering because we query 128 records at a time so if there something that is not loaded on first load it has to be fetched from server.

Comment: it works fine when I am selecting a value using mouse so there must be something kendo's click function is doing which I am not.